# Was Trevor a real person?

Tags: the-good-place

In *The Good Place*, we meet the character of Trevor, played by Adam Scott, supposedly coming to the Good Place as a representative of the Bad Place. However,

> it is revealed that the main characters of the show were actually in the Bad Place the whole time, and everyone else who was supposedly in the Good Place were actually just acting.

However, we see the character of Trevor in a video in the Medium Place, so he couldn't have just been acting. What was his place in the Bad Place hierarchy of Season 2?

Comment: He could have been putting an act with Eleanor and the other human, I don't see how being featured in the medium place video makes that an impossibility

Comment: Is Matt LeBlanc an actor?  His character on Friends is an actor, but he's just pretending to be Joey, so does that mean he isn't really an actor?

Comment: @Acccumulation: his character on [Episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episodes_(TV_series)) is an actor called Matt LeBlanc, who played Joey on Friends. Is he, in fact, *always* pretending to be Matt LeBlanc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Caution: answer involves spoilers for *The Good Place***

It is most likely he is a real demon.

Nothing is contradictory if Trevor is a demon. Whereas the other demons are pretending to be good humans in the Good Place to make the main characters torment each other, Trevor's role is to 'pretend' to have come to the (fake) Good Place to return the (fake) real Eleanor Shellstrop (really a demon.)

The Medium Place video would show him (previously) in his real role as a demon interacting with a real Good Place representative in setting up the Medium Place.

That said we have only Michael's word at this stage that the Medium Place is in fact real. While he states that it was necessary to include a certain amount of truth in his deceits, it is impossible to be certain that he is being truthful.

Comment: Yep, this is probably right, just like how Bad Janet exists both pre a and post reveal.

Comment: You can add "spoiler" quotes using ">! " markup. Note that if you want a "paragraph break", you have to either interrupt it with a non-quote, or use the BR HTML markup to introduce two line breaks.

Comment: I'd vote for the Medium place being real for the simple fact that she reveals that everyone keeps taking the darn train out to her and having their memories wiped, and she isn't playing along with Michael's game, etc. that she is a part of Michael's plans I have no doubt, as part of the torture. But that doesn't mean she is a participant in the plans, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Later episodes do reveal the Medium Place to be real

Answer (score 8):

**Trevor is definitely a demon**

This was already fairly clear as of the time that the other answers were written, but it was confirmed later on. In the third season of the show,

> Trevor shows up seeking to disrupt the group and prevent them from showing the Judge that they can achieve personal growth.

He is explicitly identified by Michael as a particularly malicious demon.

Answer (score 4):

*Warning: too many spoilers to hide behind a tag.*

---

#### Trevor must be a demon.

The Good Place where our heroes reside is a fake Good Place and is actually a Bad Place, run by demons. The Janet is a Good Janet, stolen from an actual Good Place, but all the others are demons (and a Bad Janet).

Since Trevor participates in this, he must be a demon, either from Michael's cast of demons for his Good Place, or one from another neighbourhood in the Bad Place. Note that the animosity between Michael and him might still be genuine; Michael seems to have a predilection for more sophisticated ways of torture (hence the whole Good Place set-up) while Trevor seems to like banality and rudeness.

---

The Medium Place doesn't seem to be reset when the Good Place is reset, since when Eleanor and Chidi visit it during attempt #802, Mindy St. Claire tells her she has been there 15 times before.

So it is likely that the Medium Place is not a part of Michael's experiment, even though he might be *using* it.

That means that the orientation video for Mindy St. Claire must be real, too. It shows the interaction between Bea from the Good Place (which might make her an angel), and Trevor from the Bad Place, a demon.